# Efficiency of Antennas vs operating frequency

Tags: rf, antenna

I have refereed a [document](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra351a/swra351a.pdf) from TI which mentions that antenna efficiency decreases as frequency is further decreased.

Although 136 - 240 MHz has highest range for equal power, the efficiency of antennae at that frequency is not acceptable.

What causes this effect?

Comment: physics it is..

Comment: can you offer a little explanation? I'm not good in physics but I really have to understand this.

Comment: this field is huge and far too broad for ee.se, but start by reading up on how antennas work and how they "catch" the signal.

Comment: It doesn't say anywhere that the efficiency drops with decreasing frequency. It's just a selection of antennas, with different frequency ranges and different efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An antenna needs to be of a "certain size" to be most effective at turning EM waves into electrical signals and vice versa. The size for best effectivity is related to the wavelength of the transmission/reception frequency.

For instance, a simple quarter wave monopole at 433MHz needs to be about 17 cm in length whereas at 2.45GHz this drops to about 3cm. Wavelength of an EM wave is: -

\$\lambda = \dfrac{c}{f}\$

And an effective monopole is one-quarter this length

So, if you have a bunch of antennas of approximately the same physical dimensions I would expect the higher frequency antennas to be more superior because the lower frequency ones just cannot be as effective given the limited space they occupy.

Comment: Shadesof Goldilocks and the 3 antennae. If an antenna is too big, it tends to "reflect" a signal. If it is too short, it "directs" a signal [like a lens]. When it is "just right" it will absorb or transmit the most RF energy. Look at a Yagi or TV antenna: the short bits at the front focus the beam, the long piece at the back reflects it, creating a high-gain antenna.

Comment: Andy Your answer makes a lot of sense. This means those low frequency antennae are made to be less efficient!! I have no idea why they did that.. Perhaps as you said, the actual sizes  must be too big.

Answer (score 1):

Making an antenna much smaller than a wavelength generally results in it becoming less efficient.

It's actually a bit more complicated, it's the *gain bandwidth product* that is limited. There is a theory called the [Chu-Harrington limit](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu%E2%80%93Harrington_limit) which tells us the maximum gain and bandwidth possible for a particular size antenna.

Lower frequencies do give better range for the same power and antenna gain. Higher frequencies give better range for the same power and antenna size. It depends what is  important to you.

A 136 MHz antenna can be made with excellent efficiency and gain, if you can make it full-sized for that frequency, perhaps 1 m long.

Answer (score 1):

The antennas in the paper are clearly intended for confined spaces, consequently there is a trade-off between shape, overall size, matching (to the receiver and/or transmitter), bandwidth, gain, radiation resistance, lobe pattern, etc. Generally to make an antenna shorter than an optimum length at a given frequency, inductance can be added, thereby providing an approximate 50 ohm load (or whatever) but sacrificing some aspect(s) of performance. Alternatively, to fit into a given space, the antenna can be formed into a zig-zag, but this also introduces inductance and some capacitance between adjacent zigs and zags, once again reducing performance.